# Variable in php require_once file path

Tags: php, require-once

How do you take the following and substitue part of the file path as a variable?

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/directory1/directory2/directory3/file.php';
```

I want to substiture directory2 with a variable $dir2. Simply inserting the variable as follows does not work?

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/directory1/$dir2/directory3/file.php';
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basic php syntax: strings quoted with `'` do not interpolate variables. Use a `"`-quoted string instead:

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/directory1/$dir2/directory3/file.php";
                                         ^---                                  ^---
```

or use string concatenation:

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/directory1/' . $dir2 . '/directory3/file.php';
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do this in PHP.

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/directory1/'.$dir2.'/directory3/file.php';
```

Or

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/directory1/$dir2/directory3/file.php";
```

The difference is in using ' or " for strings. When using ' You need to concatenate variables as in the example and as You already did with $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. When using ", You can  put the variables in strings "as is" or even do something like this (useful with arrays):

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/directory1/{$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]}/directory3/file.php";
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `"` will parse the variable.

```
"/directory1/$dir2/directory3/file.php"
```

And instead of depending `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, you should do something like `diranme(__FILE__)` or `__DIR__` (>= 5.3) to define a root dir.

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes prevent variable substitution. Use double quotes:

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/directory1/$dir2/directory3/file.php";
```